# Space $X$ such that $H_i(X,\mathbb{Z})\neq 0$ but $H_i(X,\mathbb{Z}_3)= 0$

Tags: algebraic-topology

I want to find a topological space $X$ such that $H_i(X,\mathbb{Z}_3)=0$ for all $i$, but there is some $i$ such that $H_i(X,\mathbb{Z})$ is non zero.

I have tried using the integral coefficient theorem to come up with an example but that hasn't been fruitful, we also have not covered the universal coefficient theorem I assume there is some way to do this question without that.

I feel I am missing some key point about homology with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}_3$. Possibly something similar to how homology with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}_2$ in a sense forgets orientation.

Comment: Do you want that result to be true for all $i$? For any $i$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the result to be true for all $i>0$, then still using the Universal Coefficient Theorem, you want $H_i(X;\mathbb{Z})\otimes \mathbb{Z}_3=0$ and $Tor_1(H_{i-1}(X;\mathbb{Z}), \mathbb{Z}_3)=0$ for all $i>0$.

Now since for any abelian group $A\otimes \mathbb{Z}_3=A/3A$ and $Tor_1(A,\mathbb{Z}_3)=A[3]$ (the $3$-torsion subgroup), you need $H_i(X;\mathbb{Z})$ to be uniquely $3$-divisible.

For instance, a space with $H_i(X;\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}_2$ for all $i>0$ would work, which can be constructed (for instance) as a bouquet of Moore spaces $M(\mathbb{Z}_2,i)$.

Comment: Another space which works is $\mathbb{RP}^{\infty}$.

Comment: Thank for the answer, I had the wrong condition for the $i$ dependence. The question wants I want to find a topological space $X$ such that $H_i(X,\mathbb{Z}_3)=0$ for all $i$, but there is some $i$ such that $H_i(X,\mathbb{Z})$ is non zero. Is there a way to do this without using the universal coefficient theorem.

Comment: You now have spaces that will work (mod 2 Moore space or $\mathbf{R}P^{\infty}$), so compute their homology some other way, for example cellular homology.