# Giving an example of a space with some homology groups

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

> Give a space $X$ such that $H_i(X;\mathbb{Z}/3) \cong 0$ for all $i > 0$, but such that there is an $i > 0$ for which $H_i(X; \mathbb{Z})$ is non-trivial.

We know that the chain complex of $C_i(X; \mathbb{Z}/3) \cong C_i(X; \mathbb{Z}) \otimes \mathbb{Z}/3$. I think the best approach is to first find a chain complex satisfying this, using as many $\mathbb{Z}$-linearizations of sets as possible so we can use a CW-complex and cellular homology to realize the chain complex.

I have done nothing useful, but as posts should show some sort of effort, this is one of my failed attempts:

Consider the chain complex

$$... \to 0 \to 0 \to \mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{1 \mapsto 6}  \mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{1 \mapsto 1} \mathbb{Z}/3$$

This has $H_1(C)$ is non-trivial since $3$ is in the kernel, but not in the image.

Tensoring with $\mathbb{Z}/3$ gives

$$... \to 0 \to 0 \to \mathbb{Z}/3 \xrightarrow{0} \mathbb{Z}/3 \xrightarrow{a \mapsto 1 \otimes a} \mathbb{Z}/3 \otimes \mathbb{Z}/3$$

using the isomorphism $\mathbb{Z} \otimes A \to A: 1 \otimes a \mapsto a$.

Fails because $H_2(C \otimes \mathbb{Z}/3) \cong \mathbb{Z}/3$.

Comment: Try to think of a space that has only trivial and $\mathbb{Z}/2$ groups in its homology.

Comment: Do you know the universal coefficients theorem?  That gives an easy criterion for what $H_i(X;\mathbb{Z})$ must satisfy.

Comment: @ConnorMalin $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^\infty$ which works, thank you. How did you come up with that?

Comment: @EricWofsey No, but we did prove something that is almost the same, namely that that $C_\bullet(X; A)$ is naturally isomorphic to $C_\bullet(X; \mathbb{Z}) \otimes A$. I don't see what criterion that gives.

Comment: Without the universal coefficient theorem there isn't a super concrete reason to come up with that example. The general idea is that torsion of different primes ignores each other.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Space $X$ such that $H_i(X,\mathbb{Z})\neq 0$ but $H_i(X,\mathbb{Z}_3)= 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3505129/space-x-such-that-h-ix-mathbbz-neq-0-but-h-ix-mathbbz-3-0)